# How do I export a transparent PNG sprite from this Illustrator file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sprite

I'm new to Illustrator. I downloaded a stock image of a bubble popping from Adobe ([link](https://stock.adobe.com/search?k=bubbles+animation&continue-checkout=1&asset_id=304672863)), but I need it in a sprite png format with transparency. When I open it in Illustrator, there appears to be 1 artboard with a bunch of layers on it:

[image]

The first row is in one group, and the second row is in another group. And then there are sub-layers, with "paths", for the boxes and numbers. Is this a common layout? How can I convert this into a sprite png?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is how everything is normally laid out in Illustrator - in layers, groups and sublayers.

If you want to rearrange the frames, ungroup once or twice, until you have just the frame groups left. Using the Select Tool <kbd>V</kbd>, you can then move them and use snapping to get them accurately placed.

You can also use the direct selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> to select objects in a group for, example if you want to delete them. Also looks like the frames have a white stroke. You may want to also select these and set the stroke to none.

Finally, remove or hide the background layer. Select all, and do *File > Export Selected*, choose PNG as the file format.

Answer (score 0):

Select all objects, and group them. Then drag that into the Asset Export palette. From there, you can export into any format, including the PNG.